# cmake - cross compiling C++ code for Android and Windows (on Windows)

Tags: android, c++, windows, cmake

I would like to create a cmake project which can generate a MSVS 2019 solution that
either builds for Windows or for Android.

I created a directory called myCmakeProject.

I created a CMakeLists.txt file and placed it in the myCmakeProject directory.

I also created a test cpp file main.cpp and placed that in the myCmakeProject directory.

The CMakeLists.txt file contains the following:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10.2)

project(projectname)

add_library(libname STATIC main.cpp)
```

I created a sub-directory called 'build' in the myCmakeProject directory.

In the 'build' directory I created a buildproject.bat file containing the following:

```
cmake -DANDROID_ABI=arm64-v8a -DANDROID_PLATFORM=android-16 -DANDROID_NDK=C:\Users\{user}\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\22.1.7171670\ -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=C:\Users\{username}\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\22.1.7171670\build\cmake\android.toolchain.cmake ..
```

When I run buildproject.bat it generates a MSVS 2019 solution and it almost looks correct, but if
I am not mistaken the MSVS solution builds a static library for an x86/x64 architecture. I need it to build for
either arm64-v8a or armeabi-v7a when building for Android and for x86/x64 when building for Windows.

How do I change my cmake project so that the cmake project either generates:

1. a MSVS 2019 solution that builds the C++ code for Windows (x86 or x64)

or

2. a MSVS 2019 solution that builds the C++ code for Android (32-bit arm or 64-bit arm)

Comment: If you have invoked `cmake` once, you can't change toolset without removing all generated project files and caches. You need two separate `build` directories, one for each type.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Yes, I am aware of that. It should be possible to pass a parameter in to the .bat file so that it either generates a MSVS 2019 solution for Android or a MSVS 2019 solution for Windows....right?

Comment: No not really. If you change from native to cross, you must remove *everything* previously created by `cmake`. Therefore it's easier to have two actual and separate build directories, one for native and one for cross.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude In that case I would like to know what the bat file should look for an Android build and what the other bat file should look like for a Windows build.

Comment: AFAICT for Android just the way you show it to us, and for Windows without the `-D` arguments.